# Unicode to UTF-8 to Unicode?

Tags: c#, xml, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm reading some data, including CDATA strings from an XML. The XML is generated by a linux machine, and encoded in utf-8. The text in the XML is again created by a person on a windows machine and may contain windows unicode symbols like „ and “. Now these symbols somehow get corrupted in the whole process. When I look at the XML with my browser, the symbols are invisible, when I paste the text into the windows editor, they are displayed as rectangles (invalid chars). When I paste them into and ascii decoder (http://www.asciivalue.com/index.php) they get untangled into their correct HTML representation. (& #132; & #147;). When I save them with unicode formatting in the editor, they will come out as 84 00 93 00.

How can I convert the XML string in C# so that these unicode symbols will be restored ?

Comment: Note (1) `asciivalue.com` is absolutely no use for any characters beyond basic ASCII. For other Unicode characters, including those smart quotes, it will generate incorrect and misleading output. (2) "Unicode" is not actually the name of any encoding. When Microsoft tools like Notepad let you save in "Unicode" they really mean the UTF-16LE encoding. There are tedious historical reasons for this misleading naming but usually this encoding is best avoided in favour of UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your terminology is confusing. Unicode is a set of characters, UTF-8 is an encoding of Unicode; you can't therefore convert Unicode to UTF-8, you can only convert between UTF-8 and some other encoding of Unicode. Similarly, "Windows Unicode" is nonsense.

I think that when the „ and “ characters were inserted into your XML file, they were incorrectly represented using their Windows-1252 codes rather than their UTF-8 codes. So your file is a mixture of UTF-8 and Windows-1252, which makes it impossible to decode. You need to prevent this happening.